# Inserting rows from one table to another starting from row 1?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

Starting to learn ORACLE SQL and here is something i dont get.

I have `EMPLOYEES` table that look like this (`hire_date` values are nulls)

[image]

And another table called `EMPHD` with `hire_date`

[image]

How can i add `HIRE_DATE` values from `EMPHD` to `EMPLOYEES` table starting from the first row and all the way down?

If i use something like this

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (HIRE_DATE)
SELECT HIRE_DATE FROM EMPHD
```

obviously i end up with hire dates added at the end of the table with all other values as null.

Sry for my english and please help!

Comment: You want UPDATE, not INSERT.

Comment: There is no such thing as "first row".  You need to use an ORDER BY clause to sort the results.  EMPHD table needs to have some sort of key column to link the two tables.

Comment: OK, i added ID column to both tables whats next?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. As @OldProgrammer says, there is no guaranteed order of the data. So that table "EMPHD" you have doesn't make much sense since it does not relate a hiredate to any employee. It should have the employee_id as well and then you can insert the hiredate for the corresponding employee. It could be useful to read up on relational database concepts a bit first.

Comment: If you added a column, then please edit your question with the updated information. Screenshots are very hard to work with, code snippets are a lot easier

Comment: @KoenLostrie ty for your answer. I managed to add ID column to both tables. how can i insert multiple rows from EMPHD table now? Or is this impossible and i must insert it by my hands row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be using merge. By using merge you can update `hire_date` column if `ID` values are matched. Otherwise only two columns' value might be inserted into `employees` table as new records but seems it's not the case due to all mutually matching 19 `ID` values :

```
merge into employees e
using (select id, hire_date from emphd) h
   on ( e.id = h.id )
 when matched then update set e.hire_date = h.hire_date 
 when not matched then insert( e.id, e.hire_date ) 
                       values( h.id, h.hire_date );
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6321c458b31b9c54c511921a5c50b340)</kbd>

Alternatively, you can use update statement directly by equality among ID values of those tables :

```
update employees e
   set e.hire_date = (select hire_date from emphd where id = e.id);
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5e578fb3939fb276ae447b3479796cba)</kbd>

Comment: Wow, you sir got my question completely right and helped a lot. Had idea of Merging but wasnt able to execute it properly.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . The update is so much simpler.